# How to update my application on android market without changing version code

Tags: android

I have uploaded my app on android market.I did some changes,and want to update it again so I am getting the error.

"The new apk's versionCode (1) already exists"

So what should I do.Plese help me

Thank you

Comment: whats the problem in doing so ..... its the mandatory versioning Android market does. Why dont you wanna update this field?

Comment: So simple , if version code is exist ,increment it and upload your app., version code is made for this purpose only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not possible as per my knowledge that without change your app version code, update app to market you must need to update it.

**Go to manifestfile >> and set version code new**

**like this ::**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0" >
```

Answer (score 2):

you get your manifest and increment the version code, example:

before:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="your.package.name"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="version name" >
```

after:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="your.package.name"
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="new version name or not ^^" >
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload new installer same application package with same version code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Change the version code (most likely incrementing it) in your manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0" >`

you must have to change your v`enter code here`ersion code

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to Dr Nik's answer (sorry, my rep isnt high enough to comment), remember to save the amended manifest before exporting the signed apk, otherwise the changes don't go through and you get the same error. Exporting doesn't autosave. Had me frustrated for 20 mins until I worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio you must also change build.gradle file which has defaultConfig method contains  versionCode

Comment: ... and? You could improve your answer by proper markup and finshing what were you about to suggest else.

Comment: there is no way update application without changing version code @dakab